# Suppressing HealthCheck.too_slow for a composite hypothesis strategy

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

I have a number of unit tests that leverage a `@composite` strategy that I wrote. The strategy is quite slow (it generates complex objects) and from time to time one of the tests fails the `too_slow` health check. When that happens, I take a deep sigh and I add

```
@settings(suppress_health_check=(HealthCheck.too_slow,))
```

to the test.

Is there a way to suppress `HealthCheck.too_slow` once and for all, for all the tests that use the slow strategy?

Comment: this looks like XY-problem: can you describe one of your `composite` strategies so we can find a way to rewrite it and make faster?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the global default settings using [settings profiles](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#default-settings), but there is no way to apply certain settings to a subset of your tests built-in to Hypothesis.

If you know you have a slow strategy I'd try to make that strategy faster - usually there are some serious optimisations available - and if I couldn't I'd just disable the particular health check.  Just re-enable it occasionally to check for unexpectedly slow tests!